# Need a code to choose randomly between options

Tags: php, random, include

I have a code to choose 4 options from a group and put it in a string but I have a little problem there.
these are my default data :

```
$PID[1] = "PID1";
$PID[2] = "PID2";
$PID[3] = "PID3";
$PID[4] = "PID4";
$CID[1] = "CID1";    
$CID[2] = "CID2";
$CID[3] = "CID3";
$CID[4] = "CID4";
```

I create a file with name Loops.php and put these code in it :

```
$Also = "1";
while (isset($PID[$Also])) {
    echo '"'.$CID[$Also]."/".$PID[$Also].".php".'"';
    $Also++;
    if (isset($PID[$Also])) {
        echo ", ";   
    }
}
```

and then I used this code in my main page :

```
$input = array(include 'Loops.php');
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 4);
$A = $input[$rand_keys[0]];
$B = $input[$rand_keys[1]];
$C = $input[$rand_keys[2]];
$D = $input[$rand_keys[3]];
```

but when I echo any of final strings it does not work.
I will be appreciated if anyone could help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you should construct a path array in `while` loop, instead use a function and put that `while` loop inside that function. Subsequently, use an array inside `while` loop and append the paths incrementally. Finally, include `Loops.php` separately, not inside `array(...);`. So your code in *Loops.php* page would be like this:

```
$PID[1] = "PID1";
$PID[2] = "PID2";
$PID[3] = "PID3";
$PID[4] = "PID4";
$CID[1] = "CID1";    
$CID[2] = "CID2";
$CID[3] = "CID3";
$CID[4] = "CID4";

function constructPathArr($PID, $CID, $Also){
    $pathArr = array();
    while (isset($PID[$Also])) {
        $pathArr[] = $CID[$Also]."/".$PID[$Also].".php";
        $Also++;
    }
    return $pathArr;
}
```

And the code in the main page would be like this:

```
include 'Loops.php';
$input = constructPathArr($PID, $CID, 1);
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 4);
$A = $input[$rand_keys[0]];
$B = $input[$rand_keys[1]];
$C = $input[$rand_keys[2]];
$D = $input[$rand_keys[3]];
```

Comment: @MohammadZahed You're welcome! Glad I could help. :-)